# limit access to some configuration pages (manage display and manage fields)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I have editor and administrator role in my website, the editor role must have `"Administer vocabularies and terms"` permission (in `admin/people/permissions` page),

How can I restrict editors from "manage display" and "manage fields" **without uncheck** `"Administer vocabularies and terms"` , so they can't access to this page : `admin/structure/taxonomy/VOCABULARY_NAME/display/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go into one of my custom modules and:

invoke a [hook_permission()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) with my new needed permission (administer display and fields) that will be granted only to admin.

Then invoke [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to alter the access control on the menu path the taxonomy module creates.

This way on install admin will be granted automatically the permission and only the roles granted this permission will be able to access that page.

Comment: with hook_menu_alter, the link will be hidden but, if copy/paste the link, the page displays !!

Comment: changing access arguments in hook_menu_alter do the trick, thanks !